# Set NSObject property - EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsobject

**Process :**

- App is on the home view controller and is requesting data on API to set an NSObject property. The request is processing on a private method.
- User change the view controller to a second view controller (the request is still processing asynchronously)
- The second view controller is loaded
- The request is ending and app return EXC_BAD_ACCESS when it setting the object property

It seems the object has not the correct memory access.

I would like than the user can switch view controller, even if there is a request pending, and the application doesn't crash.

I don't want to block the user on the view controller during loading.

**User.h**

```
@interface User : NSObject

[...]
@property (nonatomic) NSString *notification;
[...]

-(void) methodName;

@end
```

**User.m**

```
-(void) methodName{

        //there is code around but useless for this problem

        [...]

        NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

        self.notification = [[dict objectForKey:@"infos"] objectForKey:@"notification"]; //Here is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS


        [...]

}
```

**MyController.m**

```
@interface MyController ()
@end

User *user;

@implementation HomeCVViewController
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    user = [User new];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [user someMethod];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [...]//some code
        });
    });
}

@end
```

**EDIT :**

I just put `@property (nonatomic) User *user;` in MyController.h and remove `User *user;` in MyController.m . The user is not deallocated and there is no crash.

Comment: check that class object is alive or not that time.

Comment: What line is actually causing the crash?  I don't see anything declared as `NSObject` either.  This question needs a lot of clarification.

Comment: I have added some code and line causing the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Verify that `[dict objectForKey:@"infos"]` is not `NSNull` - Crash
  can be here.
- Other code looks OK.
- Also add `-(void)dealloc`to your object and put a
  break point there to verify that the object is not being released
  **before** the assignment.

Comment: You're right, the object is released before the assignment. Is there a way to solve the problem now ?

Comment: Without code where you allocate this object and perform calls it is impossible to suggest a solution

Comment: @Thlbaut please look at my answer, I described how to manage this problem

Comment: @Misha I have added the controller. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Please post where and how you declare "user" object. Also can you verify that "MyController" not being deallocated also.

Comment: Added user declaration

Comment: From the code you posted I assume that "MyController" is being deallocated prior request ends. Verify this by adding dealloc method there and put a break point in it.

Comment: The controller is not deallocated. I just put `@property (nonatomic) User *user;` on MyController.h and user is not deallocated and there is no crash. Is this way correct ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually this is correct, but I do not understand why globally declared property being deallocated when it's parent class is not. Anyway I'm glad the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your output at the `NSError`

```
  NSError *error;
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

  NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);  <----- HERE

  self.notification = [[dict objectForKey:@"infos"] objectForKey:@"notification"];
```

When you try to convert from/to JSON, improper JSON structure will cause it to crash. See the error for more information.

Comment: There is no problem with the JSON, memory is the problem. Thx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this type of error appears when object deallocated but your code try to access it's data
so, first of all, check how do you hold your User entity in memory, throw, for example, property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) User *u;
```

and make sure it is still in memory when operation completed:

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How can I check if the object is still in memory when operation completed ?

Comment: @Eiko, what exactly wrong? I can edit my answer. But technically, if we sent message to deallocated object, it can cause such problem, is it?

Comment: The code of someMethod will not produce a memory error, as u is a strong reference. You can create strong instance variables/properties all over the place and it might fix the crash, but it won't fix a broken design, and it's very unlikely to get the expected behavior. But as the OP neither posts the relevant code, not the crash message itself, this is guessing.

Comment: @Eiko, completely agreed with you, I was wrong with EXC_BAD_ACCESS and my example, i will remove it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
self.notification = [[dict objectForKey:@"infos"] objectForKey:@"notification"]; //Here is the EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

write

```
NSDictionary* infoDict = dict [@"infos"];
id notification = infoDict [@"notification"];
self.notification = notification;
```

set a breakpoint, and examine each of infoDict, notification, and self. That takes the guesswork out of it. Right now you don't even know which of these three assignments goes wrong.

And since you have lots of lines of code that are in your opinion bug free and irrelevant, chances are good that the actual bug is hiding somewhere in those lines. Remember: There is a bug in your code. Assuming that any of your code is bug free is daft, because you already know it isn't!